# How to apply Phone Number Mask in the Kendo grid filter Text box using angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have the Phone number kendo grid column having the US format (999)-999-9999, It display with format in the column grid search with column filer it does't get the records because of the format applied.

Answer (score 3):

At Last i found the solution for my above question related with kendo grid column search filter applying the phone number mask to search exact record to fetch in the search results.

```js
columns: [
           {
            field: "PhoneNumber", title: "Phone#", width: 150, filterable: {
                    cell: {
                        template: function (args) {
                            args.element.kendoMaskedTextBox({
                                mask: "(999)-000-0000"
                            });
                        },
                        showOperators: false
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                field: "FaxNumber", title: "Fax#", width: 150, filterable: {
                    cell: {
                        template: function (args) {
                            args.element.kendoMaskedTextBox({
                                mask: "(999)-000-0000"
                            });
                        },
                        showOperators: false
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
```

In the above code snippet with this mask search filter shows the exact search record which filter operator "**IsEqualTo**" applied for masked filter. And we need to hide the additional operator search in the column grid using "**showOperator**" turned as "**false**".